# Ubuntu sshd_config host key: how to give a new user the rsa key for having access thru ssh (via putty for eg)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sshd

I am having a web server with ubuntu 12.04.
I received DDoS attacks and secured it with fail2ban.
I changed the ssh port to 11111 (just for example)
In fail2ban I modified the ssh listening port to 11111 as well.

I removed privileges to all existing users (may have been compromised).
I created new users, gave them sudo rights.
I used `sudo adduser johndoe` and `sudo usermod -aG sudo johndoe` commands.

But I think I forgot to do something.
When I try to connect my webserver via ssh, port 11111, with my new user johndoe, in verbose mode, I see :

```
"debug1: connection established"
"debug1: key_load_public: no such file or directory"
"debug1: identity file /home/johndoe/.ssh/id_rsa type -1"
```

and so on.

So, how do I create those host keys for my new users ?

Many thanks in advance for your help !!!!

Tom

Comment: Did you created and set the home folder ?

Comment: Also, I think this is not the proper Stack community to answer your question. Maybe serverfault is more appropriate.

Comment: If you plan to use the same key for all of your users, you may copy the public key into /etc/skel/.ssh/authorized_key. When you first create your user (adduser) add the param --create-home which will create your user home dir with the already set ssh folder (from skel).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called PuTTYgen for windows that will generate the keys. Then copy the public key into the .authorized_keys file in the .ssh folder of the users home folder on the server.

see http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen